# raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'right_only' / 'both'

Tags: python, pandas, merge, keyerror

I try to develop python comparer. I got issue with my variable named: `compare_type` which i want to set either to `l-left join / r - right join / b - inner join (both)`

if i set `compare_type = 'l';` all works fine

Nevertheless when i do either `compare_type = 'r';` or `compare_type = 'b';` ten i got following errors:

```
   raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'both'
```

or

```
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'right_only'
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Complete code:**

```
import pandas as pd

col_to_compare = 0;
compare_type = 'r';     #l-left join / r - right join / b - inner join (both)

file1_df = pd.read_csv('filename1.csv', usecols=[col_to_compare], names=[col_to_compare])
file2_df = pd.read_csv('filename2.csv', usecols=[col_to_compare], names=[col_to_compare])

file1_df[col_to_compare] = file1_df[col_to_compare].str.upper()
file2_df[col_to_compare] = file2_df[col_to_compare].str.upper()

comparison_result = pd.merge(file1_df, file2_df, on=col_to_compare,
                             how='left' if (compare_type == 'l') else 'right' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'inner',
                             indicator=True)

comparison_result = comparison_result.loc[comparison_result['_merge'] == 'left_only' if (compare_type == 'l') else 'right_only' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'both']

print(comparison_result)
comparison_result.to_csv('result.csv')
```

**Full traceback:**

```
C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\L1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/john/PycharmProjects/L1/CsvComparer/csv_comparer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\L1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 105, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 105, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'right_only'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/john/PycharmProjects/L1/CsvComparer/csv_comparer.py", line 29, in <module>
    comparison_result = comparison_result.loc[comparison_result['_merge'] == 'left_only' if (compare_type == 'l') else 'right_only' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'both']
  File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\L1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 931, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\L1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1164, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\L1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1113, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\L1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3776, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\L1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'right_only'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you provide the full traceback? [tracebacks are really important for debugging.](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have issue with this following line :**

```
comparison_result['_merge'] == 'left_only' if (compare_type == 'l') else 'right_only' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'both'
```

**My Working Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

col_to_compare = '0';
compare_type = 'r';     #l-left join / r - right join / b - inner join (both)

# file1_df = pd.read_csv('filename1.csv', usecols=[col_to_compare], names=[col_to_compare])
# file2_df = pd.read_csv('filename2.csv', usecols=[col_to_compare], names=[col_to_compare])
file1_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "0": ["K0", "K1", "K2", "K3"],
        "1": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "2": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
    }
)

file2_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "0": ["K1", "K2", "K3", "K4"],
        "3": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "4": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    }
)


file1_df[col_to_compare] = file1_df[col_to_compare].str.upper()
file2_df[col_to_compare] = file2_df[col_to_compare].str.upper()

comparison_result = pd.merge(file1_df, file2_df, on = col_to_compare, how = ('left' if (compare_type == 'l') else 'right' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'inner'), indicator = True)

print(f'{comparison_result}\n')

comparison_result = comparison_result.loc[comparison_result['_merge'] == ('left_only' if (compare_type == 'l') else ('right_only' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'both'))]

print(f'{comparison_result}')
# comparison_result.to_csv('result.csv')
```

**Output for `compare_type = 'r'`:**

[image: right_only]

**Output for `compare_type = 'l'`:**

[image: left_only]

**Output for `compare_type = 'b'`:**

[image: both]

#### Notes:

> **I made some minor changes to debug the issue so you can avoid those.** 
> **Avoid condition string rendering in DataFrame**

Comment: instead of having separate line for row_value how to correctly place it directly in the target line? Tried just to take this but having error. Just want to have it inline without additional row_value variable.

Comment: I am not sure but I think `comparison_result.loc[]` don't supports conditional value. I may wrong but it seems this is the issue.

Comment: That's definitely not true. the issue is the order of operations. If you want it in one line, use parentheses to force the equality operator to work on the result of the conditional statements, e.g. `comparison_result['_merge'] == ('left_only' if (compare_type == 'l') else ('right_only' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'both'))`

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this. :)

Answer (score 1):

this is just a problem in your chained inequality and if operators.

```py
comparison_result['_merge'] == 'left_only' if (compare_type == 'l') else 'right_only' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'both'
```

evaluates in the following order:

```py
(
    (comparison_result['_merge'] == 'left_only')
    if (compare_type == 'l')
    else ('right_only' if (compare_type == 'r') else 'both')
)
```

When `compare_type` is `'r'`, the if statement results in the entire conditional resulting in:

```py
comparison_result.loc['right_only']
```

Which is why you're getting that KeyError.

Use parentheses to clarify the order of operations you want, or better yet, define a variable that will be more readible. In this case:

```py
if (compare_type == 'l'):
    target_val = 'left_only'
elif (compare_type == 'r'):
    target_val = 'right_only'
else:
    target_val = 'both'

comparison_result = comparison_result.loc[comparison_result['_merge'] == target_val]
```